# Message all members in server not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to make a command that sends a DM to every member in the server. The error I get is this:

`(node:4741) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'members' of undefined`

Here's the code:

```js
bot.guild.members.cache.fetch().then(membersfetch => {
    membersfetch.forEach((member) => member.send("Hello"));
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `.guild` property on the client/bot, only [`.guilds`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=guilds) which contains all of the guilds the client is currently handling.

If your bot is only used on one server, you can safely get the `.first()` one like this, then fetch the members and send them a DM:

```js
bot.on('ready', async () => {
  console.log('Bot is connected...');

  const guild = await bot.guilds.cache.first();
  const members = await guild.members.fetch();

  members.each((member) => member.send('Hello'));
});
```

If it's on more than one server, you need to get the guild ID and fetch the guild by that id:

```js
bot.guilds.fetch('222078108977594368');
```

[image]